# Add image to .ics file using javascript?

Tags: javascript, icalendar

Using ics.js https://github.com/nwcell/ics.js/ to create .ics files. How can I add a static image to the .ics file.

Comment: What are you trying to do with the image here? I've never heard of a calendar event with an image in it.

Comment: When I open the .ics file the calendar event should have an image in it either in the description or as an attachment. In description would be better.

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible. The summary and description properties of an event in an iCalendar file are plain text -- there is no way to embed formatting or images into them.

Comment: Is it possible to add as attachment?

Comment: See the specification https://icalendar.org/iCalendar-RFC-5545/3-8-1-1-attachment.html